# How to deploy war file to heroku using maven?

Tags: java, maven, heroku, war

I'm trying to deploy my application to heroku using maven plugin. But as deployment seems completed with success, application is not running.

After i run `heroku:deploy-war` goal, i have this in my console

```
[INFO] -----> Packaging application...
[INFO]        - app: fast-tundra-46883
[INFO]        - including: target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
[INFO]        - including: target/spring-simple-app-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] -----> Creating build...
[INFO]        - file: target/heroku/slug.tgz
[INFO]        - size: 13MB
[INFO] -----> Uploading build...
Sep 19, 2016 11:36:54 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com:443: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
Sep 19, 2016 11:36:54 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com:443
Sep 19, 2016 11:37:15 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com:443: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
Sep 19, 2016 11:37:15 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com:443
[INFO]        - success
[INFO] -----> Deploying...
[INFO] remote: 
[INFO] remote: -----> heroku-maven-plugin app detected
[INFO] remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
[INFO] remote: -----> Discovering process types
[INFO] remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
[INFO] remote: 
[INFO] remote: -----> Compressing...
[INFO] remote:        Done: 61M
[INFO] remote: -----> Launching...
[INFO] remote:        Released v8
[INFO] remote:        https://fast-tundra-46883.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
[INFO] remote: 
[INFO] -----> Done
[INFO] -----------
```

which indicates there are no any major errors.

When i look at the logs in heroku, i got

```
2016-09-19T22:41:51.185261+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy null by userxxx@gmail.com
2016-09-19T22:41:51.185261+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by userxxx@gmail.com
2016-09-19T22:41:51.990503+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-09-19T22:41:51.990512+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
```

which again not indicate any error. but when i navigate to address where my application suppose to run, in heroku i got logs

```
2016-09-19T22:49:17.825115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=fast-tundra-46883.herokuapp.com  request_id=4851381b-0fab-49dc-a1a6-d5ebfcad1a97 fwd="79.71.253.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-09-19T22:49:17.825115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=fast-tundra-46883.herokuapp.com request_id=4851381b-0fab-49dc-a1a6-d5ebfcad1a97 fwd="79.71.253.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-19T22:49:17.976534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fast-tundra-46883.herokuapp.com request_id=e0a1fc84-6daa-4e1f-a58d-eaf579e170d6 fwd="79.71.253.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

now I'm using heroiku maven plugin, and this how it is configured

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <appName>fast-tundra-46883</appName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried to use `<processTypes></processTypes>` as I don't have a `Procfile`. but during build i got warning

```
[WARNING] The <processTypes> value will be ignored when deploying a WAR file. Use `heroku:deploy` goal for custom processes.
```

And it doesn't change anything.

Can someone help me and tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

I think your dyno might be alseep. You can check it's status by running:

```
$ heroku ps
```

However, the `java.net.SocketException` during the deployment process is concerning. But it does look like there was a successful deploy.